# How to release anonymous delegates / closures correctly in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, closures

I'm working on a GUI application, which relies heavily on `Action<>` delegates to customize behavior of our UI tools. I'm wondering if the way we are doing this has any potential issues, e.g. whether the implementation keeps references to captured variables, class instances that declare the delegates etc?

So let's say we have this class `MapControl`, which wraps a stateful GUI control. The map has different kinds of tools (Drawing, Selection, etc.), represented by `ITool` interface. You can set the tool with `StartTool()`, but you can only have one tool active at a time, so when another tool is set previous one is stopped using `StopTool()`. When tool is stopped, a caller-specified callback delegate is executed.

```
public class MapControl
{
    ITool _currentTool;
    Action<IResult> _onComplete;

    public void StartTool(ToolEnum tool, Action<IResult> onComplete) {

        //If tool is active, stop it first
        if (_currentTool != null) StopTool();

        _onComplete = onComplete;

        //Creates a tool class, etc.
        _currentTool = CreateTool(tool) as ITool;
    }

    public void StopTool() {

        //Execute callback delegate
        IResult result = _currentTool.GetResult();
        if (_onComplete != null)
            _onComplete(result);

        //Nix the references to callback and tool
        _onComplete = null;
        _currentTool = null;
    }
}
```

In the application's `ViewModel` class we set some tool like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
    private MapControl _mapControl = new MapControl();
    public void SetSomeTool() 
    {
        //These variables will be captured in the closure
        var someClassResource = this.SomeClassResource;
        var someLocalResource = new object();

        //Start tool, specify callback delegate as lambda
        _mapControl.StartTool(ToolEnum.SelectTool, (IResult result) => {

            //Do something with result and the captured variables
            someClassResource.DoSomething(result, someLocalResource);
        });
    }
}
```

In our case the `ViewModel` class is attached to the main window of a WPF application, and there can only be one instance of `ViewModel` during the application lifetime. Would it change anything if this weren't the case, and the classes which declare the delegates would be more transient?

My question is, am I disposing of the callback delegates correctly? Are there any scenarios, where this can cause memory bloat by holding on to references it shouldn't?

More generally, what's the safe and correct way of disposing anonymous delegates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it is ok and you are not holding on to any references you don't need. With clearing the references in StopTool you no longer hold them.

Comment: I agree, I don't see a reason to do that. I would be like set all local reference variables to null :P

Comment: Not quite right. In case StopTool is not called in the context of StartTool it is correct to set those references to null.

Comment: @fencliff: If my answer helped you, please be so kind and accept it.

Comment: patience, grasshopper. Since everybody was in agreement, I wanted to wait for a bit so see if anybody would have a contrary answer. Here's your rep :)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing fine with removing the Reference to methods that way.

---

One more thing you asked:

> My question is, am I disposing of the callback delegates correctly?

You don't **dispose** methods (or pointers to methods for that matter), only classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more proper way would be:

```
_onComplete = (Action<IResult>)Delegate.Remove(null, _onComplete);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to do it this way? According to MSDN `Delegate.Remove` returns null, if the first parameter is null and so, it should be equivalent to what the OP does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure you are disposing correctly of all unused objects, I'd suggest you use tools like the [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309515.aspx) so that you can have a complete view of how your application is allocating/freeing memory.